# Why is React setState hook not updating immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call a handler from a parent function with the updated state value as an argument, however, the state does not update immediately after the setSelected is called as both console logs are printing false(the initial value). After the onClick function is completed however, it gets updated.

```
onClick={() => {
        console.log("Clicked: ", props.rank, props.suit, selected); 
        setSelected(!selected)
        console.log("selected: ", selected)
        // props.handle_card_selected(props.id, selected)
      }}
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const check_border = () => {
      if (selected) {
        return "green"
      }
      return "black"
    }
    check_border()
  }, [selected])
```

Comment: Please, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately).

Answer (score 15):

Two things you need to know about the state update in React:

- State is updated asynchronously
- In any particular render, state and props don't change; changes are only reflected after component re-renders

If you want to log the updated value of `selected`, put the log statement in the `useEffect` hook.

You can't update and log the updated value of any state variable in the same render; component will have to re-render to reflect changes due to state update.

Similarly, if you want to call a function with the updated value of `selected`, call the function from inside the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 6):

`setState` is an async function which is why it doesn't update the state immediately. There is another way, i.e. pass function in `setSelected`, through which you can achieve the required behaviour:

```js
onClick={() => {
     console.log("Clicked: ", props.rank, props.suit, selected); 
     setSelected(prevSelected => {
       // props.handle_card_selected(props.id, !prevSelected)
       return !prevSelected
     })
}}

useEffect(() => {
  props.handle_card_selected(selected)
}, [selected, props.handle_card_selected])
```

Comment: Functional update is better for what the OP is trying but if he wants to call a function he can do that using `useEffect`.

Comment: The state update function shouldn't have side-effects. It's a bad practice. Use something like `useEffect` if necessary.